# How to create a viewmodel without using kotlin ktx?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I found `kotlin extension` (`ktx`) today and tried to use it.

Using this, I tried to create a `view model` using `by viewmodels()`.

But I heard that `KTX` is going to be deprecated soon, is that correct?

Better not to use it?

So, how do i create a `view model` in the future?

`constructor`? Or `ViewModelProvider.get(this)`?

Comment: "But I heard that KTX is going to be deprecated soon, is that correct?" -- not as far as I know.

Comment: You're probably talking about the [Kotlin Android Extensions](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/11/the-future-of-kotlin-android-extensions.html) Gradle plugin. Not to be confused with `*-ktx` AndroidX libraries.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Uh..so exactly,` Kotlin Extension Gradle` is deprecated, and `ktx library` is still valid? Can I continue to use the `ktx library`?

Comment: Short version: Yes. Long version: A `something-ktx` library contains Kotlin extensions specific to `something` library. "extensions" here means additional APIs designed for ease of use in Kotlin source code. These libraries have nothing to do with the mentioned Gradle plugin.

Comment: @EugenPechanec 
Thanks for replying! thanks i understood well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, declare a private lateinit var

```
private lateinit var viewModel: DetailsViewModel
```

Then,, please try this code in your fragment's onViewCreated

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,factory).get(DetailsViewModel::class.java)
```

factory is usually injected with yout dependecy injection library